# SQL and distinct

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I'm having trouble on generating a report in MySQL.  I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    birthday DATE,
    title VARCHAR(255)
);
```

I need to generate a report that throws how many titles exist for a given month. My first idea was something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(MONTH(birthday))) AS q 
  FROM users
```

Of course that only returns how many months exist in the records. What I need is something like this:

```
Month | Count
-------------
2     | 384
5     | 131
12    | 585
```

Comment: that damn GROUP BY hehe, thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT MONTH(birthday), COUNT(*) AS BirthdayCount
FROM user
GROUP BY MONTH(birthday)
```

This will give you the month number and the count of the records in that month, thus what you are looking for.

Comment: all answers were right, yours was the most accurate, though. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
SELECT MONTH(birthday), COUNT(*)
FROM user
GROUP BY MONTH(birthday)
```

Answer (score 2):

Even simpler:

```
SELECT MONTH(birthday), COUNT(*)
FROM user
GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a GROUP BY month(birthday) in there.

```
select month(birthday), count(month(birthday)) 
from users 
group by month(birthday);
```

Comment: dude - what's with the count(month(birthday))? count(*) is the way to go - keep it simple :)

Comment: Bohemian, what is the difference in terms of performance by doing a count(*) vs count(month(birthday)) ?

Comment: Actually, there can be a performance issue.  The system deals with * differently than a value.  * represents all of the rows.  Putting a row name in their makes the system count each row individually because it is looking for nulls (which it ignores).  That brings up the next issue, which is the fact that unless you are sure there are no nulls, your count will be wrong.